# 3 horizontal divs with margin issue

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a E-commerce website for practice and the I have the div set up as follows:

```css
.small-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #87bdd8!important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}

.col-4 img {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-container">
  <h2>Merch by Elute FLP</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
      <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
      <p class="price">$29.99</p>
      <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
      <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
      <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
      <p class="price">$29.99</p>
      <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
      <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
      <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
      <p class="price">$29.99</p>
      <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
      <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm extremely new to coding and using this platform so I apologize if this looks really bad or if i'm asking a dumb question trying not to rely on tutorials and think for myself but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I want the divs to have space and when I add any margin the last div wraps.

Using Atom Framework and unsure why when code run with tool on here shows elements vertical. On Atom when I load the page they are horizontal...

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Atom with the code above it displays 3 horizontal divs but when I add margin to the css it brings the last div down but there is more than enough room on the page for it all to fit...

Answer (score 0):

Since you use columns with `flex-basis`, you have to make the div with class `row` a flex parent.

I also suggest that you use the columns for grid and style their content separately. In the example below I have created `.card` elements, which are wrapped inside the columns.

And finally - extremely important: set the box-sizing of the columns to `border-box`. This means you can set paddings to the columns (instead of margins), which will be counted in the 25% of the column width. This is why it will be better to avoid horizontal margins in this scenario, because this will break the Maths - you want 4 columns with 25% width, but where should the space between them go?

```css
.small-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

/* The columns is simplified only to shape the grid */
.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.col-4 img {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Styling the column content */
.card {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #87bdd8 !important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #1E90FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-container">
    <h2>Merch by Elute FLP</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
          <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
          <p class="price">$29.99</p>
          <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
          <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
          <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
          <p class="price">$29.99</p>
          <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
          <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
          <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
          <p class="price">$29.99</p>
          <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
          <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
          <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
          <p class="price">$29.99</p>
          <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
          <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="Pictures/JeansandTee.jpg">
          <h5>Black Graphic T-Shirt</h5>
          <p class="price">$29.99</p>
          <p>Black Shirt w Graphic 100% cotton</p>
          <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```